# BrowserSync with Superstatic middleware

Tags: firebase, browser-sync, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I'm trying to use [BrowserSync](https://www.browsersync.io) to test my Firebase Hosting project. I'd like to be to load the appropriate server settings from my `firebase.json` file.
 According to [a post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/12/a-host-of-improvements_61.html) on the Firebase blog it looks like I should be able to do so using [SuperStatic](https://github.com/firebase/superstatic) as middleware.

My `bs-config.js` looks something like this:

```
var superstatic = require('superstatic');
module.exports = {
  server: {
      baseDir: ['dist'],
      middleware: [superstatic({stack:'strict'})]
   }
};
```

When I start BrowserSync it doesn't actually seem to pass through Superstatic. I've tried a number of different configuration and none of them seem to work. Am I doing something wrong, or is there a better way to have the capabilities of BrowserSync and set the basic server config from my `firebase.json`?